# Google Spreadsheet Questions Grayed out

Tags: support, questions

Why is this question grayed out?
[image]

I de-selected the follow star in the tag pop-up:
[image]

only to realize that the tag was removed from my favorite list:
[image]

So I re-selected the tag again. What did I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have added one of the tags to your ignore list instead of your favourites list.

The easy way to check is to hover over the tag again. If the star is red then you've added it to your ignored list.

In that case just click it again twice to bring it back to yellow (favourite). If not, then I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Chris.....how do I undo that....help

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra - if you hover over the tag is the star red (ignored)? If so just click it again twice to bring it back to yellow (favourite). If not, then I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Will try and let you know.

Comment: The start is yellow and once click stays yellow, yet the tag is removed from my favourite list. Upon page refresh the tag reappear in the list but the questions remain grayed out....

Comment: At first glance it seemed a bit buggy, but I removed the tag manually from the list and added it again via the "star". Now I'm back on track.